# add class to a child dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

```
<li class="view">
    <a href="#"><span>Settings</span> </a>
    <ul >
      <li ><a>Leave Settings</a></li > 
      <li ><a href="compansatorysetting.aspx">Compensatory Settings</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

I want to add a `class="open"` in `<ul>` when i click the `<li>`.

I am using

```
$(".view").click(function () { 
   $(this).children().addClass("open"); 
});
```

It is not working. Any solution?

Comment: where is the class `mobview` ?

Comment: you assigned `view` class to `li` but your click function is working on `.mobview`.

Comment: sorry.I use `$(".view").click(function () {
                $(this).children().addClass("open");
            });`

Comment: would you please to fix the html first because we are not sure of the html
structure you have.. ul tag has no closing tag, and li.view has no closing tag

Answer (score 4):

You need to use `.parent()` or `.closest('ul')` for traversing to parent ul element:

```
$(".view").click(function () { 
  $(this).parent().addClass("open"); 
});
```

If you are looking to target inner ul elements inside clicked li, then use `.find()` selector:

```
$(".view").click(function () { 
  $(this).find('ul').addClass("open"); 
});
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to assign `open` class to only `ul` then use following code.

```
$(".view").click(function () { 
  $(this).children('ul').addClass("open"); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using wrong class

```
$(".view").click(function () {
    $(this).children().addClass("open");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

A more convenient and shorter way would be-

```
$('.view').click(function(){
  $('>ul',this).addClass('open');                     
});
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/aun1czs8/)